# array of child objects in Nested Classes and accessing child objects in .Net

Tags: vb.net, oop, class, nested-class

I have a nested class, let's call it class1 and it has class2 inside it; VB.Net eg:

```
Public Class class1

     Public Class class2
        Public Sub New()

        end sub
     end class

  Public Sub New()
    '**1) How can I define X number of Class2 objects[let's call it: Node(x)  array]** with NEW() subroutine called?
    ' this raises error: dim cls2(n) as new class2
  end sub

  Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer
     Get
        ' **2) How can I return actual number of Node() array?**
        End Get
     End Property

end class
```

Outside my class in main project I define cls1 object:

> dim cls1 as new class1

Now an array of class2 is created inside cls1. 
**3) Now,How can I access All of them[node(x) array which is created inside cls1] with all properties and methods available?**

I remember I wrote a ProcessManager class with this functionality in .net 2003, nearly 4 years age, I don't have the code now.
Please write the answer in VB.net or if you can't C#. thanks a lot and saluets to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a list:

```
Private _MyClass2List As New List(Of Class2)

Public Sub New()
  For i As Integer = 0 to 4
    _MyClass2List.Add(New class2())
  Next
End sub
```

Then your property would return:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer
  Get
    Return _MyClass2List.Count
  End Get
End Property
```

To expose the list of items, I would favor a readonly IEnumerable property:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Class2Items() As IEnumerable(of class2)
  Get
    Return _MyClass2List
  End Get
End Property
```

Comment: OK, I'm going to try that, and 3rd question:How can I access All of them outside parent class?

Comment: Expose a Public Property that is of the type List(Of Class2) and returns/updates m_MyClass2List.

Comment: @Towhid As @NoAlias commented, you would expose the list as a property.  I use an `IEnumerable(of...)` so that the list can't be modified outside the class.